# what would be the time complexity of this algorithm and why?

Tags: java, stack, time-complexity

could anyone please explain me the time complexity of this code. Thanks

```
public static Stack<Integer> sortStack(Stack<Integer> aStack) {

    Stack<Integer> rStack=new Stack<>();
    int temp=0;

    rStack.push(aStack.pop());

    while(!aStack.empty()){
        temp=aStack.pop();

        while(!rStack.empty() && temp >rStack.peek()){
            aStack.push(rStack.pop());
        }
        rStack.push(temp);
    }
    return rStack;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code yourself to see how it behaves?

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be O(n^2) since the time complexity of the inner `while` is n and it's the same for the outer `while`.

Comment: I ran this data set (`[10, 1, 5, 3, 7, 4, 6, 8, 9, 2]`) and it took 21 iterations, implying `O(N*lgN)`.  Also, a sorted stack took 1 iteration.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Worst case in N^2 (try pushing the elements to the input Stack in descending order)

Comment: @Eran Weird...so what sorting algorithm is `O(1)` in the best case and `O(N^2)` in the worst case?

Comment: @Eran Yeah, I was actually giving the worst case complexity

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's not O(1) in the best case. It's O(N) in the best case (when the inner loop does nothing, but the outer loop still has N-1 iterations).